# What is causing SwiftUI's Picker to swallow the stars on macOS?

Tags: macos, swiftui, picker

I have a SwiftUI view on macOS that displays a 5-star rating using 5 system images in an `HStack`. When I put this view as a selectable content in a `Picker`, only the first of the five stars shows up. What is causing this behavior? Custom colors are also ignored.

Here is the rating view:

```
struct RatingView: View {
    var rating: Int

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0..<5, id: \.self) { pos in
                let isFull = (pos < rating)
                Image(systemName: isFull ? "star.fill" : "star")
                    .opacity(isFull ? 1.0 : 0.2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the picker view (with a local selection just to experiment):

```
struct RatingFilter: View {
    @State var selection = "B"

    var body: some View {
        Picker("", selection: $selection) {
            RatingView(rating: 0)
                .frame(width: 100)
                .tag("A")
            RatingView(rating: 1)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .frame(width: 100)
                .tag("B")
        }
        .labelsHidden()
    }
}
```

Here is a simple ContentView I'm trying it in (The `RatingFilter` view is there twice so you can see it with and without its menu in the screenshot)

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50) {
            RatingView(rating: 1)
            RatingFilter()
                .frame(width: 150)
            RatingFilter()
                .frame(width: 150)
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    }
```

Results:

[image: Screenshot of missing stars]

I have also tried to just hardcode an `HStack` with images in the picker but I get the same results:

```
        Picker("", selection: $selection) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
            }
            .tag("B")
        }
```

Finally, it I set the picker style to `InlinePickerStyle()` I get inlined radio buttons with all the stars showing and the red color on the second item (it works but that style is not usable for me), and if I set it to `SegmentedPickerStyle()` it "flattens" the `HStack` and gives me 10 individual stars to select from (instead of two groups of 5). Wild!

Comment: I have two thoughts on this. First, forego the picker and follow this tutorial: [Adding a custom star rating component](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/adding-a-custom-star-rating-component) from Paul Hudson. The other is, if you are wedded to a picker, make your star ratings into an enum, and use the enum to populate the picker. What you want in the end is a number, not an amount of stars. The number dictates the stars, or whatever image you choose to use.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The thing is, I really wonder why this wouldn't work -- why only one of the images shows up in the picker. This tells me there is something much deeper I don't understand and I would love to learn about it. I have a workaround that gets me going for now (at first I did an enum like you mentioned and now I'm using a InlinePickerStyle() in a Popover) but that doesn't answer the question of why putting these views in a picker garbles the views.

Answer (score 0):

Picker has different allowed View generics for its different forms. Opacity would not work in a menu. Just place your images in a string concatenation or just build a string with the literal stars copied out of SFSymbols.

Comment: That would explain it. Do you know where I could find the info about which views work and how for the various types of picker styles?

Comment: Yeah, sometimes things accept a Label but then only use the image or text (i.e., in a Toolbar). Apple setup this nifty documentation system where you can test that on your own time. This is the way.